# How to only check for two values existence in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists say, for example:

```
directions = [[-1,0,1],[1,0,4],[1,1,2][-1,1,2]]
```

now, in any of the nested lists the index `[2]` is of no importance in the test.
I want to try to find if the first two values in any of the nested lists match the inverse of any other, To clarify further by inverse I mean the negative value In python code. preferable with only one line but if that not possible than a work around to get the same effect.
and if is condition is true and the third values of the two nested lists should be added together and stored in the second original list in the check function and the second list which was the inverse one should be deleted.

So

```
if nested list's first 2 values == -another nested list's first 2 values 
    add their third values together
    list delete(inverse list)
```

I hope this makes a little more sense.
I have tried this below but I still cant get it to skip the 3 value or index 2

```
listNum = 0
while len(directions) > listNum:
    if (-directions[listNum][0], -directions[listNum][1], anything(Idk)) in directions:
        index = index(-directions[listNum][0], -directions[listNum][1], anything(Idk))
        directions[listNum][2] += directions[index][2]
        directions.del(index)
```

But I don't know what to put where I put `anything(Idk)`

Comment: To clarify - when you say 'add the third values together and delete one of them', do you mean that one of the two lists has it's third value replaced with the sum of it's third value and the third value of the matching list? And by the inverse, do you mean the same values in reverse order (i.e. [1,2,5] matches [2,1,5]), or inverse as in negative (i.e. [1,2,5] matches [-1, -2, 5])? A couple of examples of where you'd count it as a match and where you wouldn't could help.

Comment: I have tried to edit the question for clarity - I believe that I have captured the meaning correctly, but it would be good for you to check it. @Kayndarr has asked the obvious question as to whether you mean inverse order or negated values as that is not clear, my other question is what sort of answer you're looking for? Pseudocode? Python? You should make that clear by pressing [edit] under your question and adding the appropriate tag(s).

Comment: a) no that does not make sense, b) perhaps you can place those in a tuple and track them in a set/dict. It sounds vaguely like a variation of the classic two-sum?